# android widget stop working

Tags: android, widget

I have an app with a widget that loads an activity to perform an action.  It works great almost always, but every so often it will be unresponsive and I will have to start the app again to get it to start working again.  Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Using `Log.d(TAG, msg)` is a good way to track what your app is doing, so that you can know where it's crashing. The root of the problem should be something specific of your app, so it's not easy to give you a reason of why it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an "Application Not Responding" (ANR) dialog these links on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704311/android-how-do-i-investigate-an-anr) and [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html) might help you find out why and debug it.