# 1000 by 1000 for loop in android sep

Tags: android

I have a code like this running on Android 2.3.3 (Nexus One)

```
for(i=0; i<1000; i++){
    for(j=0;j<1000;j++){
         do AND calculation
         do XOR calculation
    }
}
```

Is this too much calculation for android? 
I went through the debugger and the debugger lost its control after 3 iteration of the first for loop (3000 iteration total)

I am running this on a new thread like this and call this function on main ui thread..

```
public void startCalculation(ArrayList<data> featA, ArrayList<data> featB){

    newThread= new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            theFunction();
        }
    });
    newThread.start();
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you mean by "lost its control"?

Comment: It doesn't give me any error message but I wasn't able to step through the process and also I wasn't able to see the variables on the debugging tool

Comment: for debuging use Logcat ... just add code `Log.d("Tag", "Value to debug:" + value);` in loop and read values from Logcat's window in Eclipse

Comment: After the first iteration, it prints something like this about 10 lines and terminates the app CG_EXPLICIT freed 200k, 54% free 2767K/5959K, external

Comment: you have for(j=0; **i** <1000;j++) not for(j=0;j<1000;j++) in your code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah it seems likely that the process monitor killed your application because it was unresponsive. Keep long running operations off the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

Do not do this on UI thread ... use [Threads](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for long running operations

EDITed:

for debug use logcat ...
just add

`Log.d("Some My Tag", "Debuging value of smth is:" + value);`

and then read values from Logcat's window in Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You will get a [ANR (Application not responding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704311/android-how-do-i-investigate-an-anr) error if you carry out long running operations on the UI thread. You should do your heavy duty work in background threads.

Comment: you didnt say in your original question that you run it in a thread... what happens inside of your loop then, are you doing memory intensive things?