# Activity is not responding while taking pictures more than one

Tags: android, camera, android-anr-dialog

I got a problem. My activity will fail to respond when I take more than one picture. Sometimes taking even the first one has the ANR problem. I don't know why. I write the code according to DEV Guide. Here is my code:

```
    public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,OnClickListener,AutoFocusCallback{

    private Button takeShot,goBack;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Camera camera;

    private ArrayList<String> pictures;

    private PictureDAO pdao;
    public static final int PICTURE_OK=1554;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);
        pdao=new PictureDAO(this);
        initComponent();
    }

    private void initComponent(){
        surfaceView=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
        holder=surfaceView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        takeShot=(Button)findViewById(R.id.lets_take_it);
        goBack=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back_to_tab3_button);
        takeShot.setOnClickListener(this);
        goBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    /**
     * set camera parameters
     */
    private void setCameraParameters(){
        Parameters para=camera.getParameters();
        para.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        Size preSize=para.getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(para.getSupportedPreviewSizes().size()-1);

        para.setPreviewSize(preSize.width, preSize.height);
        Size picSize=para.getSupportedPictureSizes().get(0);
        para.setPictureSize(picSize.width, picSize.height);

        camera.setParameters(para);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera=Camera.open();
        setCameraParameters();
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogUtil.log(e.getMessage());
            LogUtil.log(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.autoFocus(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        releaseCamera();
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
        if(camera!=null){
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera=null;
        }
    }


    private void ICatchU(){

        camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                camera.stopPreview();

                Bitmap map =BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                File picPath=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"whycools"+File.separator+"picture"+File.separator+DateUtil.getFormattedDate(DateUtil.JUST_DATE)+File.separator+timeStamp+".jpg");
                try {
                    picPath.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                    picPath.createNewFile();
                    BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(picPath));
                    map.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bos);         
                    pdao.insertPic(new PictureInfo(picPath.getAbsolutePath(), timeStamp));
                    if(pictures==null){
                        pictures=new ArrayList<String>();
                    }
                    System.out.println(picPath.getAbsolutePath());

                    pictures.add(picPath.getAbsolutePath());
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    LogUtil.log(e.getMessage());
                    LogUtil.log(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

                camera.startPreview();

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            releaseCamera();
            Intent n=new Intent(this,Tab3Activity.class);
            n.putStringArrayListExtra("picData", pictures);
            n.putExtra("shot_time", DateUtil.getFormattedDate(DateUtil.DATE_AND_MINUTE));
            this.setResult(PICTURE_OK, n);
            this.finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id=v.getId();
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.lets_take_it:ICatchU();break;
        case R.id.back_to_tab3_button:{
            releaseCamera();
            Intent n=new Intent(this,Tab3Activity.class);
            n.putStringArrayListExtra("picData", pictures);
            n.putExtra("shot_time", DateUtil.getFormattedDate(DateUtil.DATE_AND_MINUTE));
            this.setResult(PICTURE_OK, n);
            this.finish();
        };break;
        }
    }


    private void showToastMessage(String msg){
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(pdao!=null){
            pdao.close();
            pdao=null;
        }
    }


}

----- pid 200 at 2011-12-16 08:38:45 -----
Cmd line: com.google.process.gapps

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f1a8 self=0xce48
  | sysTid=200 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006528
  | schedstat=( 545418989 6032995440 141 )
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
  at android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireWakeLock(IPowerManager.java:276)
  at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire(PowerManager.java:253)
  at com.google.android.gsf.checkin.CheckinService.launchService(CheckinService.java:167)
  at com.google.android.gsf.checkin.CheckinService.access$000(CheckinService.java:64)
  at com.google.android.gsf.checkin.CheckinService$Receiver.onReceive(CheckinService.java:101)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@4050cad0" daemon prio=5 tid=9 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4055a8f0 self=0x8c270
  | sysTid=220 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1013376
  | schedstat=( 1148267 89253041 3 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4054f928> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:107)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:80)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.RefQueueWorker.run(RefQueueWorker.java:102)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40511c08 self=0x1ba2a0
  | sysTid=213 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1717752
  | schedstat=( 9471974 67681837 3 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=7 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40511b40 self=0x185d30
  | sysTid=212 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1717688
  | schedstat=( 20164408 44832613 4 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=6 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050edf8 self=0x185bf8
  | sysTid=211 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=971936
  | schedstat=( 37893754 117636767 45 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050ed10 self=0x1a33f8
  | sysTid=210 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1597960
  | schedstat=( 15809388 276306241 17 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050ec50 self=0x186018
  | sysTid=203 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=588480
  | schedstat=( 20070264 129928190 4 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=3 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050eba8 self=0x186f58
  | sysTid=202 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=588416
  | schedstat=( 112148122 1039499175 25 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050eaf0 self=0x142738
  | sysTid=201 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=588352
  | schedstat=( 105047309 2012821363 24 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

----- end 200 -----
```

Comment: When an ANR occurs, data about it is written in a file called `traces.txt` in the `data` folder. Please add the contents of this file to your question. Also, you might want to look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704311/android-how-do-i-investigate-an-anr) to understand why ANRs happen.

Comment: sorry so late.I just posted the trace for my app below the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thread your `onClick()` to avoid locking the `UI`.