# Is it possible to have a different launcher activity with broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a strange problem here. I have an app which records the call. For this I am using Broadcast Receiver and a service running in the background all the time. But the problem is that these things don't provide an app icon, so the interaction with the user is not possible. So I created another activity and declared it in my Manifest as the Launcher activity. Now the app has the icon and clicking on that icon opens a GUI for the user. This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.callrecorderbr.activity"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

      <receiver android:name=".EavesDropperReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            <!-- <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"></action>  -->
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver> 

      <activity android:name=".MainMenuActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".EavesDropperActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity> 
    <activity android:name=".RecordingsListActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name=".PlayRecordingActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />


</application>

<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


 </manifest>
```

But this approach gives me a strange exception when the app is running and I try to record a call. The app just freezes and forces quit as soon as a user starts a call. It gives some ANR in my Logcat. here is the logcat:

```
    07-17 10:21:42.147: E/ActivityManager(59): ANR in com.callrecorderbr.activity (com.callrecorderbr.activity/.EavesDropperActivity)

    07-17 10:21:42.147: E/ActivityManager(59): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut

    07-17 10:21:42.147: E/ActivityManager(59): CPU usage from 28362ms to 28ms ago:
    07-17 10:21:42.147: E/ActivityManager(59):   system_server: 8% = 6% user + 1% kernel / faults: 1684 minor 7 major
```

And then a lot of lines about the kernel just same as above line. Can anyone please tell me what is the problem. Please help me.

Comment: ANR happens when there is a long operation in any of the threads (Usually 'main' thread). To investigate more look into traces.txt file in /data folder. The following link will help you in investigating the ANR error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704311/android-how-do-i-investigate-an-anr?rq=1

Comment: Thanx Mohan, it looks helpful. Let me try some things in my app.

Comment: That worked Mohan. It worked. You can post this comment as answer , I'll accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANR happens when there is a long operation in any of the threads (Usually 'main' thread). To investigate more look into traces.txt file in /data folder. The following link will help you in investigating the ANR error ["ANR"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704311/android-how-do-i-investigate-an-anr?rq=1)