# Why app getting Hanged?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am implementing Mobile application in android using phonegap plugin. 
I have login option in my app. Once login and keep device idle for long time like 4 to 5 minutes then app becomes unresponsive. 
Any one faced this issue before? or any suggestion to find the root cause of the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you run it in the debugger and then "break" when it becomes unresponsive to see what it's doing?

Comment: yes but there is no error.

Comment: I am suggesting you find out yourself *what* the app is doing, and in order to do that you need to use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an ANR (Application Not Responding), there is a topic about it here:

[Android - how do I investigate an ANR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704311/android-how-do-i-investigate-an-anr)

You can collect the ANR logs at: /data/anr/traces.txt

You should also check the logcat output to search for errors!