# In my android product, ANR often occurs

Tags: android

An ANR always interrupts my app.

Env:
android 4.1
CPU mips 800mz
MEM 470m
display 240*240

I don't think this is a problem with my application.

I couldn't find useful infomation in traces.txt.

This is traces.txt, the top thread log:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x2be624e0 self=0x557b5780
  | sysTid=1160 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=717388656
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=6371 stm=695 core=0
  #00  pc 00000000  <unknown>
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And log cat ANR, cpu is not high.
This is the logcat of ANR:

```
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284): ANR in com.android.settings
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284): Reason: Executing service com.android.settings/.bluetooth.DockService
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284): Load: 0.8 / 0.42 / 0.43
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284): CPU usage from 16063ms to 1267ms ago:
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   3.3% 284/system_server: 2.7% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 101 minor
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   1.2% 1160/com.android.settings: 1% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 22 minor
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0.7% 1257/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.7% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0.6% 1982/ksdioirqd/mmc1: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0.1% 669/com.android.exchange: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 47 minor
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0.3% 5/kworker/u:0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0.2% 48/dhd_cfg80211_ev: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0.2% 1971/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 4 minor
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0.1% 50/dhd_dpc: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0.1% 95/adbd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0.1% 1868/logcat: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0% 38/file-storage: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0% 45/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0% 49/dhd_watchdog: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0% 80/vold: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0% 476/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284): 6.4% TOTAL: 4.5% user + 1.8% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284): CPU usage from 1069ms to 1619ms later with 99% awake:
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   9.2% 284/system_server: 3.7% user + 5.5% kernel / faults: 1 minor
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):     7.4% 298/ActivityManager: 1.8% user `enter code here+ 5.5% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):     1.8% 316/InputDispatcher: 1.8% user + 0% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):     1.8% 317/InputReader: 1.8% user + 0% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   0.7% 5/kworker/u:0: 0% user + 0.7% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284):   1.8% 1160/com.android.settings: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
06-07 10:55:07.967 E/ActivityManager(  284): 12% TOTAL: 3.6% user + 9% kernel
```

============ full traces.txt===================
to large, i commit in my blog:

http://bocaidong.sinaapp.com/?p=145

Comment: post your code and why you think its not application problem?

Comment: It seems the ANR happens in `com.android.settings` which is not an internal android package. What is your application package?

Comment: this is a whole android project, i compile android system.(sorry i don't know how to call this.)  ANR occurs anywhere. Contact, Launcher,  Caculator ,and so on.

Comment: Are you saying you are recompiling the Android OS (Operating System)?

Comment: maybe helpful: [how-do-i-investigate-an-anr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704311/android-how-do-i-investigate-an-anr)

Comment: yes, the hardware also made by my company~

Comment: Usually there is more in the logs than just one stack trace. Sometimes one exception is caused by another. Can you please post the full log? I think it contains something that would provide a hint.

Comment: this is the full traces.txt: http://bocaidong.sinaapp.com/?p=145