# How to leave the program successfully

Tags: java, android, sockets, bufferedreader, printwriter

Today I write a program.It works successfully and is almost finished.But I found when I close the `Socket`,`BufferedReader`and`PrintWriter`,the program always shows ANR.I feel confused about that.Is there any sequence to close the program??

```
@Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                mPrintWriter.println("192.168.2.131;"+mSocket.getLocalAddress().toString().replace("/", "")+";byebye");
                mPrintWriter.close();
                mBufferedReader.close();
                mSocket.close();
                net_.interrupt(); //This is the thread to send and receive data.
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

This is my question and I want to eliminate this bug to keep my program perfect.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [Android - how do I investigate an ANR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704311/android-how-do-i-investigate-an-anr)

And maybe try something like that

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

      thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                mPrintWriter.println("192.168.2.131;"+mSocket.getLocalAddress().toString().replace("/", "")+";byebye");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                mPrintWriter.close();
                mBufferedReader.close();
            }

            try{
                net_.interrupt();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                mSocket.close();
            }
        }
     });

     thread .start();
    }
```

And at the end of your app you should join that thread

```
   thread.join();
```

Comment: It's succeed.Thanks a lot. :D