# Unable to find the log for "ANR" while debugging

Tags: android, debugging, android-logcat, android-anr-dialog

I had been debugging my application for a week, I had a log file but I cannot be able to identify which application the ANR logs belongs to, Please help me find out the below things,

1. How to find out the ANR for Specific package in the log files.
2. Where the logfiles is located in android, Whether every application having one log file or Same log file for all the applications.
3. How to debug those log to clear all the ANR.

Thanks

Comment: Check this SO post for better answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704311/android-how-do-i-investigate-an-anr

Comment: Check for log "CrashAnrDetector" in your logcat output.