# Android ANR : How to debug /data/anr/traces.txt file

Tags: android, performance, android-anr-dialog

Below is the trace when android settings application got ANR. Can any one help me understand what does this means to find out the root cause ?

Cmd line: com.android.settings

```
JNI: CheckJNI is on; workarounds are off; pins=0; globals=241

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x418d1578 self=0x41879200
  | sysTid=3804 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075535868
  | state=R schedstat=( 1407544347 1054154639 7321 ) utm=82 stm=58 core=2
  #00  pc 000049a4  /system/bin/linker
  #01  pc 00001845  /system/bin/linker
  at com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLImpl._eglGetDisplay(Native Method)
  at com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLImpl.eglGetDisplay(EGLImpl.java:109)
  at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initializeEgl(HardwareRenderer.java:1019)
  at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:979)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1536)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks !

Comment: @DroidDev code? What code? All I see is a stack trace.

Comment: I have also seen this type of ANR traces in one of my application I followed this but no luck - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704311/android-how-do-i-investigate-an-anr

Comment: @jan-dovorak I took a look at the traces.txt file in /data and I see a trace for settings application. This is what I see in the trace. How can I find out where is the exact problem?

Comment: @Jitesh, I saw the link you shared, but those logs are different then mine, in my log the thread is not in TIMED_WAIT state instead its NATIVE in my case and i do not understand how can i identify why/who caused the ANR in settings app

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ***ChkBugReport*** tool developed by SonyMobile

You will get `chkbugreport-0.4-185.jar` from [here](https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/ChkBugReport/downloads)

Usage

- adb shell bugreport > bugreport.txt
- java –jar chkbugreport.jar bugreport.txt

Readability of your bug report will be get enhanced.

[Reference](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/01/25/new-bugreport-analysis-tool-released-as-open-source/)

Comment: Thanks @don-chakkappan, I saw the tool (requires to generate the bug report using bugreport tool ), but i just have traces.txt file with me. Is there a way to debug that log ?

Comment: I know how bug report works, but tool cannot help me debug just traces.txt which is generated when ever there is an ANR. Presently i cant run the first command as you mentioned on customers phone. I just have traces.txt file from which i have to identify the ANR cause