# Strange behavior - App suddenly producing ANR

Tags: android, git, performance, realm, android-anr-dialog

**I know it sounds strange/ridiculous, but I am having this issue**

**Update#2**

I am sharing the code that is indicated by @EpicPandaForce.

*SyncService.onNetworkSuccess*

```
public void onNetworkCallSuccess(Response response) {
    List<TransactionHistory> historyList = (List<TransactionHistory>) response.body();
    if(historyList != null && historyList.size() > 0) {
        TransactionHistory max = Collections.max(historyList, new Comparator<TransactionHistory>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(TransactionHistory o1, TransactionHistory o2) {
                return o1.getUpdatedAt().compareTo(o2.getUpdatedAt());
            }
        });

        if(max != null) {
            session.putStringForKey(Session.timeStamp, String.valueOf(max.getUpdatedAt()));
        }
        for(TransactionHistory history : historyList) {
            String id;
            if(history.getTo().equals(history.getFrom()) ||
                    history.getFrom().equals(session.getStringForKey(Session.fpIdKey)))
                id = history.getTo();
            else id = history.getFrom();


            LatestTransactionResponse latestTransactionResponse = new LatestTransactionResponse();
            DateTransactionResponse dateTransactionResponse = new DateTransactionResponse(DateUtility.getDateFromEpoch(history.getEpoch()));

            dateTransactionResponse.addTransaction(history);
            latestTransactionResponse.setArchived(history.isArchived());
            latestTransactionResponse.addTransaction(history);
            latestTransactionResponse.setId(id);
            dateTransactionResponse.setId(id);
            LatestTransactionRepository.getInstance().addLatestTransaction(realm,
                    latestTransactionResponse);
            ContactTransactionRepository.getInstance().addNewTransaction(realm, dateTransactionResponse, id);
        }

        try {
            Activity temp = MyFirebaseMessagingService.getRunningActivity();
            if(temp != null) {
                if(temp instanceof MainActivity) {
                    ((MainActivity) temp).refreshLatestTransactions();

                } else if(temp instanceof TransactionDetailActivity) {
                    ((TransactionDetailActivity) temp).refreshOnMainThread();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

*addNewTransaction*

```
public void addNewTransaction(Realm realm, final DateTransactionResponse response, final String id) {
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            List<TransactionHistory> tempHistoryList;
            DateTransactionResponse temp = realm
                    .where(DateTransactionResponse.class)
                    .equalTo("id", id)
                    .equalTo("date", response.getDate())
                    .findFirst();

            if(temp == null)
                realm.insertOrUpdate(response);
            else {
                tempHistoryList = temp.getTransactions();

                for(TransactionHistory history : response.getTransactions()) {
                    boolean found = false;
                    for(int i=0; i < tempHistoryList.size(); i++) {
                        if (history.getId().equals(tempHistoryList.get(i).getId())) {
                            if(history.getStatus().equals(tempHistoryList.get(i).getStatus())) {
                                found = true;
                                break;
                            } else {
                                tempHistoryList.get(i).setStatus(history.getStatus());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(!found)
                        tempHistoryList.add(history);
                }

                //realm.insertOrUpdate(temp);
                realm.copyToRealm(temp);

                //DateTransactionResponse transactionResponse = temp;
                //temp.deleteFromRealm();
                //realm.insertOrUpdate(temp);
            }
        }
    });
    //removeDuplicateTransactions(realm);
}
```

*removeDuplicateTransaction*

```
private void removeDuplicateTransactions(Realm realm) {
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            RealmQuery<DateTransactionResponse> query = realm.where(DateTransactionResponse.class);
            RealmResults<DateTransactionResponse> results = query.findAll();
            List<DateTransactionResponse> transactions = new ArrayList<>(results);
            for(DateTransactionResponse response : transactions) {
                List<TransactionHistory> historyList = response.getTransactions();
                Set<TransactionHistory> historySet = new LinkedHashSet<>(historyList);

                RealmList<TransactionHistory> histories = new RealmList<>();
                histories.addAll(new ArrayList<>(historySet));

                response.setTransactions(histories);

                realm.copyToRealm(response);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

**Update#1**

There are 3 tabs with `RecyclerView`s on my main screen. Below are the implementation of `Adapter` for all three.

I have been developing an App for quite a time. It has been working just fine and I occasionally work to improve its performance. It is still under development. Some days ago, I cut-out the branch and done nothing notable (just one or two bug fixes) and started testing it and OOPS it started giving `ANR`'s. I revert back to previous branch and very strangely it started giving me the same result. I have removed all changes and tried, still the same result. I am not sure what's happening. I tried to study `traces.txt`, but couldn't find `waiting to lock` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704311/android-how-do-i-investigate-an-anr) SO answer.

I have also difficulty reading `traces`, couldn't find the culprit. [Here](https://ufile.io/ppse1) is the `traces.txt` file.

I am using `Realm` as Database in my application and couldn't find a way to perform operations on `Realm` on other thread. I tried to find any other culprit in code, but all is till the same as before which was working perfectly fine.

**Hierarchy**

Here is the App Hierarchy.

Login screen is shown and user enters PIN. Then comes the main screen. Main screen contains 4 tabs, just like WhatsApp i.e first tab is camera and rest contains `RecyclerView`s in which data is being populated from `Realm`. ANR is only happening here. Keeping in mind that it was literally perfect some days ago until I took branch out and fixed some bugs, which were not even related to the main screen.

Any help or direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: any heavy operation you are performing on main thread?

Comment: or you fetching heavy amount of data from database?

Comment: Yes, from `Realm` database. It's not that much heavy, but more importantly it was very smooth. It starts happening now.

Comment: Well I also had trouble reading the traces file: `{"success":false,"error":404,"message":"Not Found"}` :P

Comment: Do you by chance use `copyFromRealm()`?

Comment: If you can post the data fill code and the adapter code and the query and all that then that would be great

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have edited the link, you can see it [here](https://ufile.io/ppse1). NO, I didn't use `copyFromRealm` anywhere. I will update my question with adapter code. Thanks

Comment: It says you are doing write transaction on UI thread, and also you are most likely doing it per item instead of in a single transaction. You generally shouldn't run write transaction on UI thread

Comment: at io.realm.BaseRealm.commitTransaction(BaseRealm.java:320)
  at io.realm.Realm.commitTransaction(Realm.java:126)
  at io.realm.Realm.executeTransaction(Realm.java:1326)
  at com.pakrupay.app.realm.repository.ContactTransactionRepository.removeDuplicateTransactions(ContactTransactionRepository.java:310)
  at com.pakrupay.app.realm.repository.ContactTransactionRepository.addNewTransaction(ContactTransactionRepository.java:405)
  at com.pakrupay.app.service.SyncService$1$1.onNetworkCallSuccess(SyncService.java:109)

Comment: So you should add code for SyncService.onNetworkSuccess, addNewTransaction, and especially removeDuplicateTransactions

Comment: Glad to see you've added code, but you should have added `ContactTransactionReposito‌ry.removeDuplicateTr‌​ansactions` (and `addNewTransaction‌`). :p

Comment: There is no way that `performFiltering()` method works correctly!!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your direction. I would love to hear suggestions about `performFiltering`, it is working so far.
Moreover, all the methods you are indicating are already run, they are not causing the issue (i think, I might be wrong). I am sharing code though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163089/discussion-between-waqas-ahmed-ansari-and-epicpandaforce).

Comment: Welp, that's a bit more complicated than for me to just start changing parts of it. The write transaction should be off the UI thread. You could even try using executeTransactionAsync and its onSuccess callback

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce, it improved execution a lot. But again the problem is as it was. All of these realm executions are already run when this happens.